# Traduzir texto de ajuda no título das perguntas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Está traduzida a legenda do campo, mas não está traduzido o texto de ajuda:

[image: Printscreen]

**Sugestão:**

> Qual é o erro, pedido de funcionalidade, ou meta-tópico de discussão? Seja específico.

Comment: O título no SOPT também não está traduzido: `What's your programming question? Be specific.` Sugestão: `Qual é a sua dúvida sobre programação? Seja específico.`